# regular expressions starting and ending with a fixed string in java

Tags: java, regex

`\*122\*12345678#`

How to match this string for *122* is start, # is end, and 8 numbers in the middle?

Comment: Have you looked at any online tutorials before coming here? Try tutorialspoint: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, show your effort here.

Comment: I recommend to play with regular expressions at e.g. https://regex101.com/ to get a hang of it

Answer (score 3):

```
^\*122\*(\d{8})#$
```

- `^\*122\*` start with `*122*` (* need to be escaped using `\`)
- `(\d{8})` 8 digits
- `#$` ends with #

You can test and check your regex expression using online sites as https://regexper.com/

As @Zabuzard noted, if you don't need to capture digits and search string as a whole, you can use simpler expression:

```
\*122\*\d{8}#
```

Comment: but i need to use \*123* as start

Comment: you can not see the star symbol in front of the 122 and end of the 122? or i can not see yours?

Comment: got it. thank you guys.

Comment: @ZHIMUZHANG you can accept the answer if it helped